# Is it more resource efficient to close a scanner or reassign it?

Tags: java, performance

For example if I had

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
scan.close();
scan = new scanner(new File("file.txt"));
```

would that be faster than

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
scan = new scanner(new File("file.txt"));
```

Or is it essentially the same runtime and uses the same resources?

Thanks

Comment: Note that `Scanner#close()` closes its underlying `InputStream`, so unless you want to close `System.in`, don't do it. For any other `InputStream` source, it's recommended and essentially necessary to `close()` it.

Comment: It's not a choice. You have to close the old scanner. Merely reassigning the variable that referred to it doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `scan.close()` you are freeing the underlying resource. Not calling the function is faster (even if it was a no-op, there is some time associated with performing a call and return), but will likely result in the resource being held open (and possibly locked) by your program until your program exits.